# Changing info tab title

Tags: layout

I am working with EE1.14 and I am using custom package based on rwd theme.

I want to change "Description" tab title but no luck.

I was using in app/design/frontend/my_package/theme/layout/local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Cru Notes</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I searched everywhere before I asked question, and couldn't find an answer.

Thank you

Comment: What did you put in your local.xml?

Comment: I edit the question, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, at the end it was easy.

I created translate.csv file in:

```
app/design/frontend/my_package/theme/locale/translate.csv
```

and I just added this line:

```
"Description","Notes"
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to change the title of description tab if you are using theme based on rwd. Follow below steps to do so:

1) Goto `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEMEPACKAGE/default/layout/catalog.xml`

2) search for below code somewhere near line 200

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
 </block>
```

3) Replace the name "**Description**" in between `<value>` tab of `<action method="setTitle">` to your desired name.

Comment: thanks for this, I prefer my solution with only small change in translate.csv file. I don't like copying all the xml files in my theme layout folder. I like to have there just local.xml and custom xml connected with custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

I try to Find Any Solution But I do not get Any solution from layout to handle the Description Tab.

This is not standard Solution, So I try to Fix through view.phtml of My theme file.
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml line no 170

```
 <?php $this->getChild('description')->setData('title','My Custom Description Tab'); ?>
```

before tab functionlaity.

OR You Can Also Use this Tag in Local.xml File of Your theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="product.info">
     <remove name="product.description"/>
     <block type="catalog/product_view_description" before="product.attributes" name="my.product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>My Description</value></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Thanks